# Calculating geodesic curves on the graph of the gaussian function

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I am trying to calculate the equation of the shortest path between two points on the graph of the function
$z=e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}$. I think the paramtrization that gives the most comfortable metric $g_{ij}$ is this:
$$\varphi(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,e^{-ar^2})$$
the metric is
$$(g_{ij})=\begin{pmatrix}
1+4a^2r^2e^{-2ar^2} & 0\\ 
 0&r^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$
The geodesic equations and euler-lagrange equations are both turn out really 'ugly'. Is there any other way to find geodesic on this surface? I'll appreciate guidance.

Comment: I computed the Christoffel symbols and geodesic equations: they are actually mild after all! There are way more ugly equations than those. Don't expect closed form solutions for generic geodesics.

Comment: The rotational symmetry gives the constant of motion $r^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\text{const.}$ for geodesics $(r(t),\theta(t))$, which may be useful.

Comment: As @Kajelad mentioned, this surface is a surface of revolution, and so the geodesics have a very nice conceptual description. See Clairaut's relation in a differential geometry text (e.g., p. 73 of [my text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf)).